# Which div is currently active?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a series of divs ( displaying graphics). Click one graphic div and something is written in a div.

```
$("#graphic1").click(function(){  
   $("#text").html("Something important goes here.") 
}
```

But if the user clicks graphic1 when graphic8 is displayed I want it to do something else

```
if (graphic8 was active before graphic1 was clicked){
   do this
} else {
   do that
}
```

To explain further

1. there are many divs.
2. any one of these divs may be active at one time.
3. when selecting a new div I would like to know which div was active BEFORE the new div was selected.

EDIT 9/14 in response to answers

Here's a quick example at jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/2DEnY/2/

I would like that for the divs to
1. toggle
2. when selecting a new div that the description is displayed below. I tried and failed doing combinations of if/else clauses.
3. After this little bit is done (and I think solving this would solve the next) I would like it that the text description be able to be different depending upon which div was previously active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose your html structure looks like

```
<div id="graphic1" class="graphic">
</div>
<div id="graphic2" class="graphic">
</div>
<div id="graphic3" class="graphic">
</div>
...
```

you js code goes like

```
$(".graphic").click(function(){  
   var $before = $(".graphic.active"); //previously active div, do what ever you want,
                                       //remember to check whether $before is null or equals to 
                                       //$(this)
   $before.removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");

   $("#text").html("Something important goes here.") 
});
```

Comment: Jason, I must be missing something important. Following your example - I "ought" to be able to something like writing to the previously active div. Something like:   $before.html("I was here");

Comment: hmmm. that's looking interesting. let me work with it for a while. thx.

Comment: Thank you. I worked on it more. I got far further than I was before. But now I hit a new snag. I am able to :
    1. Select a new div and Change the highlight within the active div and 
    2. Change the text in the text area.
    3. Toggle the active div and remove the text. BUT NOW
    4. if the user selects the active div a third time the text ought to show again.  I have an example: http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/V2SeD/1/

Comment: new question solved, i answered it in comment section of the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/V2SeD/2/

Comment: Thx. Not quite there. Example: [1] Click on div 1 (text for div one appears below.) [2] Click on div 2 (text for div two appears below). [3] Click on div 2 again (hide text) [4] Click on div 2 again and text for div 2 appears again. ---- At first this was simply an issue of perfecting the UI. Now I want to know how to do this. It's killing me. By the way, thx again for your help.

Comment: updated, but this is quite ugly code, just show you how to implement it http://jsfiddle.net/V2SeD/3/

Comment: that was it!!!! thx. I'll look it over and hopefully will figure out what I was missing.  again. tx.

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to whatever item that has been click, and for every new click select the class, read whatever you want from that element, remove the class and then add it again to the new item.

Made a fiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/dPwkE/

**jQuery:**

```
 $(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        if($('a.active')[0]){
           $('a.active').removeClass("active");
           $(this).addClass("active");
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Well after reading the edit, as far as i understood, you could use data attributes to store some content for each div then display it once pressed.

somehting liek this perhaps?
http://jsfiddle.net/2DEnY/4/

Comment: Thank you Breezer but it's not what I'm looking for. Following the example you gave here's two things I would like for it to do.

Comment: @user2734400 what missing?

Comment: Oh. My comment was truncated. I edited the original post and put up a jsfiddle example. I would like to be able to "know" the active div and work with it. So. If div1 is active and the user clicks div2 I would like to be able to know this. example if (div1 == active && div 2 is clicked) {show this great information}elseif (div1 == active and div3 is clicked) {show this} ... I've tried numerous combinations and have failed each time.

Comment: @Mayo join me in the cahtroom and ill instant help you
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37394/jquery-help

Comment: thanks for the invite. But you need 20 reputation points to join in the conversation.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I wish I could have asked a few questions. I'm close to getting this but I must be missing a few simple things. I have a new example: http://jsfiddle.net/MAYO/V2SeD/1/      I have everything working except now I have a toggle problem. You see that you're able to go from div to div but when you select the same div - after toggling the first time it doesn't toggle back. I tried toggle but it doesn't work. (Maybe I'm just getting tired.)